# Trigger on UserPackageLicense object?

Tags: managed-package, user-management

I have a requirement for a managed package that we are developing. I need to make an API callout to an external system when user is assigned to the package (hybrid package on user based pricing model). The ideal solution would be to have a trigger in the UserPackageLicense object to do this. However, UserPackageLicense doesn't support triggers at the moment. Can anyone suggest a work around?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: According to [SOAP API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_userpackagelicense.htm), it supports DML. Could you not create a Custom Object that almost mirrors the  UserPackageLicense?

Comment: Yeah. I know it supports DML. But the thing is the assignment happens from the standard Manage Licenses UI. So, I am wondering on what action I can create custom object record that mirrors UserPackageLicense.

Comment: If I'm understanding you right (sorry if I'm not!), given that assignment happens from the standard UI, why not do the actions in a Custom Object instead? Then if a licence is updated on the Custom Object, update UserPackageLicense, if a licence is created in the Custom Object, create one in UserPackageLicense?

Comment: @DanJones Thanks for your interest in clarifying this further. When I say "from standard UI", I am talking about the Manage Licenses screen which is used to provide access for users to the package. By what you are saying, I believe we may need to come up with our own custom page to do this assignment. I am not sure if we can override the Manage License screen with custom page

Comment: Does your callout needs to be instant? If not then you can create a scheduled job to query UserPackageLicense records with creation date is <=now-15 min then if query returns records you can send callouts accordingly. You'll only need to schedule job to run every 15 min after writing the scheduled class.

Comment: @tugce This is what I am doing now. However, I need it to be done instantly.

Comment: You can achieve this with a process builder which call an invockable method. I did something similar for assigning user license automatically. https://kevansfdc.blogspot.com/2017/05/automatic-package-license-assignment-to.html